# R - apply adf.test by group - add p-values to data.frame

Tags: r, grouping

I am using

```
g <- lapply(split(bbm, list(bbm$variable, bbm$ticker)), function(x) testx(x$value))
```

with `str(g)` and `str(g[g != "NULL"] )`, respectively, where `testx` is defined as

```
library(tseries) # for adf.test
##
testx <- function (x) {
    return(tryCatch(adf.test(x), error=function(e) NULL))
}
```

to get the results from an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test grouped by the 2 variables `ticker` and `variable`.

How can I extract the p-values and add them to my initial data.frame as a column?

Here's a sample of my data:

```
            ticker                    variable   value
1  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 29898.0
2  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 31302.0
3  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 29127.0
4  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 24056.0
5  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 22080.0
6  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 22585.0
7  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 22674.0
8  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 21733.0
9  1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 22016.0
10 1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 21999.0
11 1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 22013.0
12 1002Z AV Equity        BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS 21135.0
13 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 28476.0
14 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 29446.0
15 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 29273.0
16 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 27579.0
17 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 20769.0
18 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 21370.0
19 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 22306.0
20 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 21013.0
21 1002Z AV Equity                 BS_TOT_LOAN 21810.0
22 1002Z AV Equity          BS_TIER1_CAP_RATIO     6.5
23 1002Z AV Equity          BS_TIER1_CAP_RATIO     6.2
24 1002Z AV Equity          BS_TIER1_CAP_RATIO     7.9
25 1002Z AV Equity          BS_TIER1_CAP_RATIO     9.2
26 1002Z AV Equity          BS_TIER1_CAP_RATIO     8.5
27 1002Z AV Equity          BS_TIER1_CAP_RATIO     6.6
28 1002Z AV Equity          BS_TIER1_CAP_RATIO     9.6
29 1002Z AV Equity BS_TOT_CAP_TO_RISK_BASE_CAP    11.5
30 1002Z AV Equity BS_TOT_CAP_TO_RISK_BASE_CAP    10.9



 > dput(head(select(bbm, ticker, variable, value), 30))
structure(list(ticker = c("1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", 
"1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", 
"1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", 
"1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", 
"1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", 
"1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", 
"1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", 
"1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity", "1002Z AV Equity"
), variable = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L), .Label = c("PX_LAST", "PE_RATIO", "VOL_MEAN", 
"BS_CUSTOMER_DEPOSITS", "BS_TOT_LOAN", "*", "RN366", "BS_TIER1_CAP_RATIO", 
"BS_TOT_CAP_TO_RISK_BASE_CAP", "RETURN_COM_EQY", "BS_LEV_RATIO_TO_TANG_CAP",
"NPLS_TO_TOTAL_LOANS"), class = "factor"), value = c(29898, 31302, 
29127, 24056, 22080, 22585, 22674, 21733, 22016, 21999, 22013, 
21135, 28476, 29446, 29273, 27579, 20769, 21370, 22306, 21013, 
21810, 6.5, 6.2, 7.9, 9.2, 8.5, 6.6, 9.6, 11.5, 10.9)), .Names = c("ticker", 
"variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: oh sorry, I forgot to mention: `testx <- function (x) {
    return(tryCatch(adf.test(x), error=function(e) NULL))
}`

Comment: Thank you for providing the `dput` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(bbm)`).  Grouped by "ticker", "variable", we apply the `testx` function on the "value" column.  We get a summary output of 5 new columns, from which we can select the "p.value" (`testx(value)$p.value`) and assign (`:=`) to create a new column ("pval") in the original dataset.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(bbm)[,pval := testx(value)$p.value , by = .(ticker, variable)]
```